# Tableview rows resizing on selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have setup a tableview to use self-sizing cells (in fact I didn't have to do anything more than use auto layout - it seems that `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is the default rowHeight).

The cells are sized correctly:

[image]

However, when I push another controller on to the stack, the cells immediately resize just before the transition animation:

[image]

They remain at the incorrect size when I pop back to the table view controller. I can partially resolve this part by reloading on `viewWillAppear` to recalculate the correct heights, but then I lose some other animations and selection state.

Is this an iOS bug? How might I work around it?

[Here](https://github.com/benpackard/CellHeightTest) is a sample project that demonstrates the same.

Comment: Try to setup estimated height of your rows

Comment: You'll also notice that if you rotate to landscape, the cells aren't the right height either. @deathhorse is correct. You need to set the tableview's estimatedRowHeight, which you can do in viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Should have read the docs closer. Either of you can leave an answer if you would like it accepted, or I will add it otherwise in a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set estimatedRowHeight:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
}
```